# Is there a way to only replace part of format string?

Tags: python

Example:

```
format_string  = "http://somedomain.com/%s/%d"
format_string %= ('somestring', %d)
print(format_string)
>>> http://somedomain.com/somestring/%d
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Stick another `%` in front of the `%d`. Where are you getting these strings from?

Comment: Did you want 10 to appear in your final string? Such as `http://somedomain.com/somestring/10` or `http://somedomain.com/somestring/%10`?

Comment: This is not valid Python code. The value of  `format_string` should be enclosed in quoted. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @LutzHorn I made multiple mistakes. Sorry I was tired, needed to sleep, not post questions on stackoverflow. :)

Comment: here is a lame trick I've used once:  `"hello{{}}{}".format(2).format(1)`  -->  `"hello12"`

Answer (score 2):

The string interpolation requires that you have 1 item for each "conversion specification" in the string.  However, you *can* escape a "conversion specification" with another % ...

```
format_string = 'http://somedomain.com/%s/%%d'
print(format_string % 'foo')
```

---

Of course, a complete "hack" (that will only work if you're trying to replace a `%s`) is to put another conversion string in place of the original one...:

```
format_string = '%s%s'
print(format_string % ('foo', '%s'))
```

Again, this probably doesn't work in your scenario...

---

Other options are to use the `.format` style string formatting *and* write your own [formatter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting).  Note, this isn't for the faint at heart -- but here's a basic example<sup>1</sup>:

```
import string

class MyFormat(string.Formatter):
    def vformat(self, format_string, args, kwargs):
        out_lst = []
        iargs = iter(args)
        for tup in self.parse(format_string):
            literal_text, _, format_spec, _ = tup
            if literal_text:
                out_lst.append(literal_text)
            if format_spec:
                try:
                    out_lst.append(format_spec % next(iargs))
                except StopIteration:
                    out_lst.append('{:' + format_spec + '}')
        return ''.join(out_lst)


print(MyFormat().format('foo {:%s} {:%d}', 'a', 10))  # foo a 10
print(MyFormat().format('foo {:%s} {:%d}', 'a'))  # foo a {:%d}
```

<sup><sup>1</sup>This is my first attempt to ever actually write one of these ... It's possible that it can be done more cleanly and I'll happily accept any improvements...</sup>

Comment: I guess, you meant `*args, **kwargs`.

Comment: Interesting, but how do we use a custom `string.Formatter` subclass when calling `str.format`?  `MyFormat().format(template, *vars)` is kind of lame ...

Comment: @sobolevn -- Nope, I meant what I said.  Notice I overrode `vformat` but called `format`.  The latter is a thin wrapper around the former which does argument unpacking for you.

Comment: @wim -- no idea... I don't think it's possible.  Note that the formatter we created is stateless for all intents and purposes -- We could probably make a global one and just pick off the method...  `my_format = MyFormat().format` -- Now it's just `my_format(fmt_string, a, b, c=d)` which is a bit nicer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of string formats in your string to achive this:

```
>>> a = '{} is %s'
>>> print a.format('This')
This is %s
>>> print a % 'not good'
{} is not good
```

But it is not a recommended behavior.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the recommended way, kind of like a workaround, but you can try string.replace, or re.sub

Example:

```
format_string.replace("%s", "something") 
>>> 'http://somedomain.com/something/%d'
```

Of course, if you can have complicated string formats, then it's best to write a custom formatter. However, if you urls are simple like this one, this approach is simple and easy to understand.

You can also make it general, using a function like this:

```
import re
def replace_next(url, value):
    return re.sub("%.", str(value), url, count=1) 

replace_next(format_string, "something")
>>> 'http://somedomain.com/something/%d'
```

However, you might encounter percent encoding in urls, so you can get a bit more adventurous:

```
import re
def replace_next(url, value):
    return re.sub("%\D", str(value), url, count=1)
```

I hope this can help you solve your problem.